# Simple jQuery function and action order

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a very simple function where after click body class fades out and replacing class.

```
$(".a").click(function () {
    ('body').fadeOut();
    $('body').removeClass();
    $('body').addClass("green");
    $('body').fadeIn();
 });

 $(".b").click(function () {
     $('body').fadeOut();
     $('body').removeClass()
     $('body').addClass("pink"),
     $('body').fadeIn();
 });
```

The problem I have is that the class is changing before the body will fade out which is opposite to what I am trying to achieve.

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Dom

Comment: `removeClass`  and `addClass` are no effect functions. So they are not queued.

Answer (score 3):

The `fadeOut` method takes a callback to run after the fade finishes.
You can change the class in that callback:

```
$(".a").click(function () {
    $('body').fadeOut(function() {
        $('body').removeClass().addClass("green").fadeIn();
    });
});
```

Comment: You can replace the inner `$('body')` with `$(this)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Such a simple solution. Well still leraning. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use callback functions.

```
$(".a").click(function () {
    ('body').fadeOut(function(){
         $('body').removeClass();
         $('body').addClass("green");
         $('body').fadeIn();
     });
 });

 $(".b").click(function () {
     $('body').fadeOut(function(){
         $('body').removeClass()
         $('body').addClass("pink"),
         $('body').fadeIn();
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('body').fadeOut(function(){
    $(this).removeClass().addClass("green").fadeIn();
});
```